# Can't login to StackExchange network - 408 error

Tags: bug, login

Every time I try to login to any StackExchange network site from my home PC (in the UK), I try to login through Google.  I'm redirected to the Google login page, I enter my Google username/password correctly, and then the browser hangs on a blank screen for a while, before giving me the following:

```
408 Request Time-out
Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.
```

This happens in Google Chrome, Firefox, and SeaMonkey, each time I created a new profile to try logging in.  I'm only able to post this bug from my server in America, from which I am able to login.  Help!

Google Chrome's developer tools, "Network" tab, shows that the request that hangs, and then gets a 408, is a GET request to this URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate/?s=...
```

Comment: Chrome F12 --> Network tab --> please check what request is being stuck, maybe it'll shed some light over what's going on. Might be something blocked on your end.

Comment: Added the network data to the question.

Comment: Edit it out please, anyone browsing it will be logged in with your credentials. Edit: done it, asking a mod to nuke the revision. Sorry about that, should have warned not to copy the full URL here! :/

Answer (score 3):

OK, I tried disabling my software firewall and I was able to login.  For some reason that was blocking the login URL!  Problem solved.